# Unable to access some tables in Redshift which are external from Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

No data is getting printed when I run the table in redshift which has huge data and it is working fine in Athena but not in redshift, can anybody help me with ways to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple causes of this issue:

1. Role you have created external table does not have access to S3 bucket.
2. If the role has access to S3 bucket that also needs to be associated with the redshift cluster.
3. There could be a S3-based policy restricting the getObject access with bucket name or bucket_name_* in the resources.
4. Check if there is endpoint created in VPC for S3 bucket and check any policy restricting the S3 bucket access..
5. For testing, create separate bucket load data into it, and try creating an external table using data. catalog and check if it is accessible.